# Multicolor tint an image with imagemagick/graphicsmagick

Tags: imagemagick, graphicsmagick

I would like to tint an image multicolor. Like the popular rainbow tinted images you see ( for example here: http://www.popsugar.com/tech/How-Make-Facebook-Profile-Picture-Rainbow-Colored-37785769 )

How could I do that using imagemagick or graphicsmagick.

Comment: This is easy, but there is many ways to do such a thing. Just drop the image to gray scale & compose/composite over colorbands. Can you show what you tried, or perhaps, what's not working?

Comment: Thanks! Your comment helped me figure it out. I had tried something similar but didn't convert to grayscale first, and the result looked terrible

Comment: That's great to hear. Please post your solution as an answer, we'd love to see it!